# I have label and radiobutton list in table cell, but it displays up-down not in single line

Tags: asp.net

I have label and radiobutton list in table cell, but it displays up-down not in single line.

```
<asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="65%">
    <asp:Label ID="lblGatePass" Text="Select GatePass Type :" runat="server" CssClass="PCLabel" />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblIo" CssClass="RadioButtonList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#073957">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Inward"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Outward"></asp:ListItem>   
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:TableCell>
```

Comment: This might be because of the width of the cell. If you increase the total width of the table or maybe just the width of this cell, do you still have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try this one?

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblGatePass" Text="Select GatePass Type :" runat="server" CssClass="PCLabel" />
            </td>
            <td>
                 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblIo" CssClass="RadioButtonList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
                AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#073957">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Inward"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Outward"></asp:ListItem>   
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the the RepeatColumns property if you use the table layout

```
<asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="65%">
<asp:Label ID="lblGatePass" Text="Select GatePass Type :" runat="server" CssClass="PCLabel" />
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblIo" CssClass="RadioButtonList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#073957">
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Inward"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Outward"></asp:ListItem>   
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</asp:TableCell>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.repeatcolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Edit 2 :
If you use the flaw layout you must increase the container size